# speed of calling System.DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

when I run the following code it shows the elapsed time equal to zero but when I comment the first line it shows elapsed time equal to 20ms! why?

does calling System.DateTime.Now loads something in runtime and this cause the difference?

```
string time1 = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
string te = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(); ;
Console.WriteLine(te);
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: @dcastro ,yes I've tried it many times.

Comment: did you try CTRL+F5 in release mode?

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I'm running it in vs2010 debug mode.

Comment: Then the delay is probably caused by the debugger, you should run without debugging in a release build.

Comment: This is entirely normal, both the operating system and .NET are *lazy*, doing things at the last possible moment.  Lots and lots of stuff happens when you use DateTime.Now, it is likely to be your first pinvoke call and ultimately ends up deep inside Windows kernel mode.  Big chunks of code need to be located and loaded into RAM.  Keeping your hard drive very busy.  Big reason that everybody likes an SSD so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disassembling `mscorlib` and analysing the results, that twenty millisecond delay may very well be caused by `DateTime.Now`.

At least in version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, that property calls the internal `TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc()` method. That method, in turn, invokes `TimeZoneInfo.s_cachedData.GetOneYearLocalFromUtc()`, which may exhibit a performance penalty on the first call (when that data is not cached yet).

Depending on the result of that call, `TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc()` can also invoke `TimeZoneInfo.GetIsDaylightSavingsFromUtc()`, which is non-trivial and involves date arithmetic.

Comment: Would this only exhibit issues on machines outside of the US?

Comment: @Michael, why would it? There are several timezones in the US, and some of them implement DST.

Comment: The only reason I'm asking is because I'm just not able to reproduce this type of behavior.

Comment: @Michael, honestly, there are many factors that could result in such a performance penalty, and your answer about the debugger is spot-on. I only tried to determine if a one-shot perf loss could be explained by the code in `DateTime.Now`, since the questioner apparently reproduces this behavior in release mode.

Comment: And your analysis is quite amazing. There is a lot going on under the hood and if any one of those broke to be executed, the cache most interestingly, it would cause a delay of some sort. But now I wonder why the OP is apparently able to reproduce it in `Release`, without the debugger, consistently. At any rate, +1 for the sheer amount of transparency you've provided here my friend!

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, *never profile in `Debug`.* Further, even in `Release`, *never profile with the debugger attached.* Your results are skewed and hold no real value.

This code, in `Release` takes `0` milliseconds. I executed it and verified that output. Below is the output:

```
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I try it in release mode but the same result!

Comment: @abdolahS, you pressed `CTRL+F5` when running it, in `Release` mode, right?